# Eclipse Android Custom Activity Class File (subbing for autogen activity file for new project)

Tags: android, eclipse

When I create a "New Android Application Project," I would like Eclipse to proceed with its normal actions with (at least) one customization.

I want Eclipse to create the new Activity.Class file using fuller @Overrides rather than just the onCreate(), such as also providing onStart(), onResume(), onPause(), onRestart(), and so on.

In other words, I want a more verbose Activity.Class file generated than is already done by Eclipse.

Going further, I would also like Eclipse to add my own inner classes - if that is not asking too much.

In short, is there a template in Eclipse that I can tailor for this customization?

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of a way to accomplish this within the "New Android Application Project Dialog", but you  add additional overrides to each activity yourself by clicking the Source dropdown menu, then Override/Implement methods..., and then select each method you would like to override.

I'm not sure what you mean by add your own inner classes. You can do this easily yourself, I'm not sure what additional functionality Eclipse could provide.

Comment: All the things I can do easily are things that could be done by Eclipse easily - one would expect.  I could use notepad otherwise if I wanted to keep the old chain and ball on and re-write code every time I author a new project.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=android%20custumized%20code%20templates&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CEQQFjAC&url=http://es.droidcon.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Custom-Android-Code-Templates.pdf&ei=ZF5QUZX_H4XD4AOu5oDICQ&usg=AFQjCNE8x-0rEdIlkAm5Bz8VR4tCiqaVDw&sig2=p4eNpIWT6Gzrd1uJhpMnjw&bvm=bv.44158598,d.dmg) might answer your question. There's a templates directory in your Android SDK where you can add or alter the XML templates.

Good luck,

Bp